# Deploying with git, empty folders with Composer

Tags: php, git, deployment, composer-php, slim

I'm trying to deploy my Slim app. I'm using [SlimController](https://github.com/fortrabbit/slimcontroller); both Slim and SlimController are loaded in `composer.json`:

```
{
  "require": {
    "slim/slim": "2.*",
    "slimcontroller/slimcontroller": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

I have replicated my localhost evironment on my VPS: Ubuntu 13.04, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5.3. I deploy with git to a bare repo. Everything works on localhost, and everything was working fine  on the server by pushing to the repo and running a `post-receive` git hook to move the files into the public Apache folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/site
git checkout -f dev
```

When I installed SlimController with Composer and pushed to the repo again, I can see the folder `vendor/slimcontroller/slimcontroller` was created, but it's empty! It has all the files on my localhost, and the app works, but on the server it has nothing, and the app throws an exception because it can't find the SlimController class.

I made sure the folder has all the necessary permission when I created the bare repo and then running these commands (my user is already part of www-data group that owns Apache):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/site
chmod -R g+rw /var/www/site
```

I don't know what's going on. When I commit and push it all looks good, but then the folder ends up being empty for some reason. I tried adding other packages with Composer and same problem, path gets created but folder is empty on the server. I tried `composer install` from scratch a bunch of times, and while the `Slim` folder gets copied correctly the others do not. I'm clueless... Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: `vendor` is in my git repo. It was added with `git add`. I just tried adding `cd /var/www/site && composer update` to the `post-receive` hook and it runs, but still same issue, package folders are empty, except for Slim.

Comment: well you should not put `vendor` under git. If you must do that for deployment reasons (e.g. no composer on the remote), then don't run composer on the remote. Remove vendor from the repo, ensure you committed the lockfile and then on remote remove the vendor folder, then run `$ composer self-update`, then run `$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check` and then finally run `$ composer update -v`.

Comment: Already have Composer in localhost and remote but I'm not quite following. So you're saying to add `vendor/` to `.gitignore`, then add `composer update` to the hook, then push?

Comment: It woooorks!!!! Thank you very much, I'll accept if you post as answer.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. What specifically worked?